# Banco de dado sem chave estrangeira no Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Assisti um aula onde é criado um sistema de estoque no Laravel onde existe o produto e a categoria. Mas não existe chave estrangeira, somente uma coluna categoria_id. Como é feito esse relacionamento? Esse relacionamento é feito na aplicação?

Comment: Só pra entender a tabela produto nao tem uma chave para tabela categoria é isso?

Comment: Não tem. Só tem o campo categoria_id. Não tem chave estrangeira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deveria ter a relação da [chave estrangeira](http://www.devmedia.com.br/breve-conceito-de-foreing-key/17426) relacionando as tabelas **produto** e **categoria**, isso é um fato. Diferente disso pode funcionar via código, mas, o agravante são as consultas que terão certa lentidão e se por acaso tentar gravar na tabela de **produto** uma **categoria** inexistente, vai funcionar, por não haver a [*integridade referencial*](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms184276(v=sql.105).aspx), por isso a programação deverá suprir essas brechas que poderam surgir na codificação.

> Como é feito esse relacionamento?

#### Model Categoria

```
class Categoria extends Model{

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'categoria';
    protected $fillable = ['descricao'];
    public  $timestamps   = false;

    public function produtos() {

        return $this->hasMany(Produto::class, 'categoria_id','id');
    }

}
```

---

#### Model Produto

```
class Produto extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'produto';
    protected $fillable = ['descricao','categoria_id', 'valor'];
    public  $timestamps   = false;

    public function categoria() {

        return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class, 'categoria_id','id');
    }

}
```

<sub>***Observação:*** as configurações do `model` basicamente são essas, e o correto é que seja explicita como nos dois `model` apresentados, é uma boa conduta principalmente para manutenção. Outro observação é que os campos são meramente ilustrativos e como exemplo de uma relação entre tabelas feita no [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel)</sub>

> Esse relacionamento é feito na aplicação?

Sim o relacionamento é feito via ***codificação/programação***, ou seja, em cada `model` que representa uma tabela do seu banco de dados. Vale lembrar que isso não impede do `model` **Produto** gravar uma **Categoria** inexistente, como já explicado não tem [integridade referencial](http://www.devmedia.com.br/breve-conceito-de-foreing-key/17426).

***Referencias:***

- [Breve Conceito de Foreing key](http://www.devmedia.com.br/breve-conceito-de-foreing-key/17426)
- [Integridade de dados](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms184276(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Eloquent Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)
- [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Entendi. Na model categoria e produto está como vc colocou e é como é ensinado no curso. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seria um  relacionamento de Um para Muitos(One to Many)

Um exemplo de relacionamento um-para-muito é um produto pode ter varias categorias
Voce pode modelar o relacionamento assim:

**Model**

```
class Categoria extends Model{

    protected $table = 'categoria';

    public function produto() {

        return $this->hasMany('Produto', 'categoria_id');
    }

}
```

Na documentação do laravel tem mais detalhes sobre esse relacionamento
http://laravel.artesaos.org/docs/5.0/eloquent

Answer (score 1):

No conceito de [Banco de Dados Relacional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banco_de_dados_relacional), são necessárias chaves estrangeiras para que exista relacionamento entre as tabelas, se `Produto`não tem um `categoria_id`, isso pode significar que o relacionamento pode ser muito para muitos, dessa forma:

```
class Produto extends Model{

    protected $table = 'produto';

    public function categoria() {

        return $this->hasMany(Categoria::class);
    }

}
```

Ou seja, cria-se uma terceira tabela, que indica o relacionamento entre as duas:

```
Tabela: produto_categoria
        categoria_id -> foreingkey->referencia(id)->em(categoria),
        produto_id -> foreingkey->referencia(id)->em(produto)
```

Comment: Na verdade minha dúvida não é bem esse. É que não existe chave estrangeira nas tabelas. Pelo que entendi o Laravel faz os relacionamentos através de funções é isso?

Comment: As funções usam as chaves estrangeiras para fazer os vinculos.